# Loop through values concatenating each to put in one cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, concatenation

I want to compare dates to find the ones that overlap.

The first function I created checks for full overlap, partial overlap, or no overlap.

This is the 2nd function. It will be used to expand upon the partial overlap process, comparing what does in fact overlap, and provide either a sequence of dates that are between the overlapped range, or to create the first date with a dash and last date that overlap.

Code I have so far:

```
Public Function partialdates(SD1 As Integer, ED1 As Integer, SD2 As Integer, ED2 As Integer) As String

'This function will be expanded, but the first If statement takes 1 case such that the first set of dates overlaps, but not beginning with the start date: SD1 = 1885 ED1 = 1969, SD2 = 1897 ED2 = 1972

    Dim i As Integer 
    Dim years As Integer
    Dim difference As Integer

    If SD1 < SD2 And SD1 <= ED2 And ED1 <= ED2 And ED1 >= SD2 Then
        difference = ED1 - SD2
        For i = 1 To difference

' I need help with this, to create a sequence of years that will be what are 
' overlapped, such as 1897, 1898, 1899...etc

            years = years & ", " + 1           
        Next
        partialdates = years
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: do you need this only for years overlap or for date overlap?

Comment: Only for years, and technically all of the years used are strictly numbers. I recently discovered I can't compare anything prior to 1900 as years, so I just instead converted everything to numbers for comparison. So for this example, I should get the number 72 for my difference, and use that as my I to difference for loop. For each iteration, I want to add 1 to SD2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inherently lazy about collecting arrays of values as strings, so I usually just use a Scripting.Dictionary and then just join the keys when I'm done:

```
Public Function partialdates(SD1 As Integer, ED1 As Integer, SD2 As Integer, ED2 As Integer) As String
    If SD1 < SD2 And SD1 <= ED2 And ED1 <= ED2 And ED1 >= SD2 Then
        Dim difference As Integer
        difference = ED1 - SD2

        Dim years As Integer
        years = SD2
        With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 1 To difference
                .Add years, vbNull
                years = years + 1
            Next
            partialdates = Join(.Keys, ", ")
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the function body with the following lines:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim difference As Integer

If SD1 < SD2 And SD1 <= ED2 And ED1 <= ED2 And ED1 >= SD2 Then
    difference = ED1 - SD2
    partialdates = ""
    For i = 1 To difference

' I need help with this, to create a sequence of years that will be what are
' overlapped, such as 1897, 1898, 1899...etc

        partialdates = partialdates & IIf(partialdates = "", "", ", ") & (SD2 + i)
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty crappy vb thing I used to use to sift through dates and find overlapping dates. Im just sharing this - it is not directly answering your question but may give you some idea of where to start? I stored all the start and end dates into and array and just looked through it that way. I finds the greatest overlap by storing each overlap in an array of (0,0) dimensions (you coul change this if you want all the dates stored). It also really only works if the array is in order. If i needed this now I would just dump all the dates in an access table and just query so the order of the list wouldnt it matter. Or i could rewrite this in vba to do the same thing

```
            Dim ChkArray(0,0) as date

            For l = LBound(UACFArray, 1) To UBound(UACFArray, 1)
                For m = LBound(UACFArray, 2) To UBound(UACFArray, 2)

                Select Case StartDate

                    Case Is = UACFArray(l, 0)
                        EndDate = UACFArray(l, m)

                    Case Is <> UACFArray(l, 0)

                        If StartDate > UACFArray(l, 0) And StartDate < UACFArray(l, m) Then
                            For c = LBound(ChkArray, 1) To UBound(ChkArray, 1)

                                ChkArray(c, 0) = UACFArray(l, 0)
                                ChkArray(c, 1) = UACFArray(l, m)

                            Next c

                        End If
                End Select

                Next m
            Next l
```